# Object going through wall during collision

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I'm making a game which uses very simple collision detection. I'm not using box 2D because it's an overkill. Basically, it's a mix of Pong and fooseball. As the ball gains speed and has a very high velocity it ends up going through the wall it's supposed to collide with. The code works with slow and regular speeds, but not with very fast motion.

This is a snipet of my code:

pos.x is a vector which holds the x position of my ball.

```
if (pos.x - radius < wallLeft)
{
        pos.x = wallLeft + radius;
        vel.x *= -1;
}
```

What could i do to improve this?
thanks

Comment: Does the ball only go through the wall in one direction?

Comment: Does the ball goes through temporarily and bounces back too late or doesn't it bounce back at all? Also, we would need types of those fields and how exactly you're doing the movement calculation before this.

Comment: Try setting a break-point on the if-statement's conditional check, so you can see why it's not registering. Are you using pos.x as an unsigned integer?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. After the velocity is really high, it goes through and does not come back. Depending on where the ball starts, it goes through either of the walls after it's reached that very high speed.

Comment: @lucas: I rather meant, are x, radius and wallLeft (unsigned) integers or floating point (and what size). This could account for overflowing

Comment: @ KillianDS they're ints but not unsigned. Why would this cause overflowing? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing wallLeft a bit, so that the balls speed is never greater than wallLeft, it seems that after your ball goes below 0 it glitches (or you have some code for that that I don't know), not familiar with the framework or how the rest of your code works, but that's the easiest way to solve it. If you don't want to do that, there's probably a code somewhere that does something if the ball's x is less than 0, and you'll have to make that a bit more lenient, maybe make it so that if the ball's x is less than -50, or something like that (play around with the number until it works)

Comment: I don't think so, it sounds to me like the wall goes from wallLeft to the left side of the screen, the wall would grow, but it's the easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably if (pos.x - radius) == wallLeft then the ball is already touching the wall and its velocity can be reversed; if you add this as an additional test in the loop does it help?

Comment: I put that into the if statement and i did not get anything. Was worth the try though. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only idea I am having is that the speed is so high that you get an overflow when adding it to the position, making pos.x > wallLeft + radius again.

Comment: I have a feeling that the speed becomes higher than the framerate so the program can't account for the ball's position when it goes through. The program is running at 60fps. Does that make sense?

Comment: @lucas: not really, if it misses it on the first frame it should get it on the second as you actually check if it's behind the wall, not if it overlaps with the wall. Even if it then would over/underflow it actually should come out at the other side (if the calculations there are similar). So I think we're missing some code.

Comment: Yes, you should post more code here. The snippet above doesn't show enough.