# How to implement a good collision system which also will be cost efficient?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am working on a simple ping pong game where I want to implement a simple collision system for my ball and racket. What I did was to check which `pos(x,y)` the ball had and compared the current `post(x,y)` both of the rackets had to see if they were at the same `pos` (`pos` as in `position`).

This seemed to work until I increased the ball's speed. Then sometimes the ball would go through the racket (I believe this is since the ball's speed is greater than the width of the racket). See related answer by @MarkCF: [Object going through wall during collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197513/object-going-through-wall-during-collision).

One implementation to solve the problem would to limit the speed of the ball so it is never greater than the width of the racket. But I believe it would be fun to have any speed of the ball which is why I was looking for another implementation. I had the idea of instead of updating the ball's position with `ballPosX = ballPosX + speed` updating it `SPEED` amount of times in a `for-loop`.

**My question is:** Is this way of checking collision a bad implementation since I will call the method `ball->update()`, `speed` amount of times which I assume wont be cost efficient? And as a sidenote, if my game is updating the ball's position `speed` amount of times, am I going away from the object oriented programming concept since my game now has a part in updating my ball's position?

**My current code:**

```
bool checkCollision(Ball &ball, Rack &p1, Rack &p2) {
    if (ball.getBall()->x <= p1.getRack()->x + p1.getRack()->w
        && 
        (ball.getBall()->y >= p1.getRack()->y && ball.getBall()->y <= p1.getRack()->y + p1.getRack()->h)) {
        ball.changeDir();
        return true;
    } else if (ball.getBall()->x >= p2.getRack()->x
        && 
        (ball.getBall()->y >= p2.getRack()->y && ball.getBall()->y <= p2.getRack()->y + p2.getRack()->h)) {
            ball.changeDir();
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    Rack *player1 = new Rack(10, 0, 10, 200);
    Rack *player2 = new Rack(1260, 0, 10, 200);
    Ball *ball = new Ball(3.0, "green"); // 3.0 is the ballSpeed in this scenario

    ball->update(); // Moves the ball with the speed of ballSpeed
    if(checkCollision(*ball, *player1, *player2)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

**My own idea of a collision:**

```
int main() {
    Rack *player1 = new Rack(10, 0, 10, 200);
    Rack *player2 = new Rack(1260, 0, 10, 200);
    Ball *ball = new Ball(3.0, "green"); // 3.0 is the ballSpeed in this scenario

    for (int i = 0; i < ball->getSpeed(); i++) {
        ball->move1px();
        if(checkCollision(*ball, *player1, *player2)) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

I was also looking into this for collision but I am not sure if its a good implementation for a ping pong game: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/39931/fast-accurate-2d-collision

Comment: You know the position and size of the ball before and after moving it. You know the position and speed of the racket. It's possible to calculate if doing that move would cause the racket and ball to intersect at any point along the balls path. Here's some good reading material on the subject : [Pool Hall Lessons: Fast, Accurate Collision Detection Between Circles or Spheres](https://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131424/pool_hall_lessons_fast_accurate_.php?print=1). It's not *exactly* your problem, but close enough to be of use to you.

Comment: Did you consider predicting whether the ball will be behind the bat next time? If yes calculate the interception location by find the cross of the balls trajectory and the bat.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes that seems alike atleast and will probably help me figure out a collision system. But does that mean my current implementation + the implementation I had in mind are both bad / incorrect ways of doing it?